# How to count rectangles that contain a point in sql

Tags: sql, algorithm, teradata

I have the following problem in SQL (Teradata). I am given a series of (thousands) of overlapping rectangles on a grid. Is there an efficient way to store the rectangle data so that, using only SQL, I can calculate for each point the number of rectangles that contain it? In certain cases we are talking thousands of rectangles and millions of points. A small scale example:

On a 5x5 grid, with two rectangles coords (x1,y1,x2,y2)  at (1,1,4,4) and (2,2,5,5), the resulting matrix would be

11110
12221
12221
01111

How would I calculate this using sql? The final data format would be a table with the columns "x" "y" and "count" where count indicates the value in the matrix at x,y

Comment: Have you heard about OGC Simple Features standard? It defines a common model for storing spatial data in a relational database. I remember using PostGIS, which is an implementation of the standard for Postgres, and there were built-in in functions that do exactly what you're asking for (finding elements contained in, intersections, etc.). I don't know much about Teradata, but [this article](https://developer.teradata.com/extensibility/articles/putting-teradata-geospatial-on-the-map) says it complies with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your rectangles in a table `rects` with columns `x1`,`y1`,`x2`,`y2`, i.e., two pairs of columns, one for each coordinate. For a given point `(x,y)` you retrieve the number of rectangles containing it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rects WHERE x1 <= x AND x2 >=x AND y1 <= y AND y2 >= y
```

Comment: You did not include used indexes in your answer. And with simple index on (x1, x2, y1, y2) it will not be very effective unless rectangle size is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not familiar with Teradata, but usually what you want in this kind of case is an R-Tree, and it seems like Teradata supports it - http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1181_112A/Introduction.117.18.html#ww15453925.

Then you do something like this (pseudocode):

```
CREATE TABLE rects (
 id integer primary key,
 box RECTANGLE,
 INDEX `idx_box` (box) USING GIST
);

SELECT * FROM rects where ST_CONTAINS(box, POINT(x, y));
```

If maximum size of your rectangle is limited and much smaller then the whole area though, a simple approach like in lex82's answer will work just fine with a little tuning (again, pseudocode):

```
CREATE TABLE rects (
  id integer primary key,
  x1 <whatever your coordinate type is>,
  x2 ...
  y1 ...
  y2 ...,
  INDEX (x1, y1)
)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rects 
  WHERE 
       x1 BETWEEN (x - MAX_RECT_SIDE) AND X  -- These 2 to hit the index
   AND y1 BETWEEN (y - MAX_RECT_SIDE) AND y
   AND (x2 >= x) AND (y2 >= y)
```

The idea here is that if maximum rectangle size is known and small enough, you basically have a bounding box for upper-left corner of the rectangles you're looking for using simple 2-column numeric index.